# how to distribute a number into numbers of cells?

Tags: arrays, google-sheets

I have a sheet for the employees leaves so for example if:

Employee A takes Annual leave for 4 days starting 1/1/2021 I want to distribute the days into cells for these days to be like this:

**A | 4 | 1/1/2021**     1/1/2021 2/1/2021 3/1/2021 4/1/2021

I want to have each day date into a single cell.

any idea how to achieve that, please

Answer (score 1, accepted):

or:

```
=INDEX(TEXT(SEQUENCE(1, A2, B2), "d/m/yyyy"))
```

[image]

Comment: One more thing please, if i want to populate leaves into the days as calendar how can i do it?
i tried Index & Match but its not working, also query :( I made a sample sheet here: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/15uIG-hQ_n9Ivpo5UPI3M7Ae2t5ndZbn0OQBPnX-K0Ts/edit#gid=0

Comment: i sorted it out using filter formula, but i guess its super complicated. i made the sheet public.

Comment: @RedaElbarbary use: `=ARRAYFORMULA(IFNA(VLOOKUP(A18:A&"¤"&B17:17, QUERY(SPLIT(FLATTEN(IF(C1:10="",,A1:A10&"¤"&C1:10&"×"&B1:B10)), "×"), "where Col2 is not null"), 2, 0)))` see your sheet...

Comment: Thank you so much @player0 and so sorry for the late update. im really thankful for all your helps.

Comment: im just wondering why you used this sign " ¤ " & " × " ?

Comment: @RedaElbarbary those are unique symbols. they serve as separators for SPLIT. you can use any symbols you wish: ♀♪♫☼♦♣♠♥☻☺

Answer (score 1):

try:

```
=INDEX(TEXT(TRANSPOSE(ROW(INDIRECT(B2&":"&B2+A2-1))), "d/m/yyyy"))
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you Player0 it worked!!, miss your magical formulas <3. happy new year :)

Answer (score 1):

Or:

```
=ArrayFormula(B2+SEQUENCE(1,A2,0))
```

Comment: Just be aware that, if you need to do anything with the dates (compare, do math, etc.), they won't work directly with formulas that turned them into text. If you are just going to look at the dates, then a wider array of formulas will work.

Comment: Oh ya thats terribly annoying me now and i dont know how to get other this. i have to copy-paste data as value in order to use it with formulas. do you have any fix for this? Thank you so much for your insights.

Comment: @Reda, I'm not clear on what you mean. Are you saying that you have to copy and paste-as-value the original date in B2? Or are you saying that you have to copy and paste-as-value the result of other formulas you tried on this page? If the latter, did you try my formula? It does not convert dates to text, so it should produce all dates. If those dates wind up being numbers in the 40000 range, that is a "raw date"; in that case, just be sure to either format the results range or click your original date in B2, click the format painter icon, and then "paint" the results range.

Comment: Oh i see, that one worked. thank you soooo much Erik.

Comment: Happy to hear it, @Reda. Would you please mark my post as "Best Answer" so that this issue will be marked as resolved? Thank you.